# Possible metrics on the space $C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

I had a question that what are all the possible metrics on the space $C[0,1]$ of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$. This question arose when I was trying to prove that

$$\mathscr{F} := \left\{F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t) \mathrm{d}t\ \bigg{|}\ f \in C[0,1], \|f\|_\infty \le 1 \right\}  $$
is bounded and equicontinuous subset of $C[0.1].$
Now I could prove this if I know a particular metric however I don't know what is the metric in this context on $C[0,1]$. So it would be nice if I know some metrics on the space (except the usual, defined as $d(f,g) = \int_0^{x} |f(t) - g(t)|\ \mathrm{d}t$). Or is this true for any metric? A more general question comes to the mind that for a given metric space (with one metric given), how many metrics can one define on it? (I know this seems a little vague, I would grateful if someone can edit my question). Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the space of continuous functions we usual take the supremum norm. That is $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ (respectively, we take the metric induced by this norm). Note that $d(f,g)= \int_0^x \vert f(t) - g(t) \vert dt$ is a metric only if $x=1$ (otherwise the metric "sees" only the behavior of $f,g$ in the interval $[0,x]$).

Comment: What you refer to as 'the usual' is not the usual. (It is not a metric unless $x=1$). The usual one is $d(f,g)=\sup \{|f(x)-g(x)|: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$. For this metric the family $\mathcal F$ is bouded and equicontinuous but for your metric it is not.

Comment: So if I define the metric as $d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \|f-g\|_\infty \mathrm{d}x$ then should it solve the problem?

Comment: $\|f-g\|_{\infty}$ is a constant. Why are you writing an integral?

Comment: For the metric $d(f,g)=\int_0^{1}|f(x)-g(x)|dx$ the given family is not equicontinuous.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ok so as you suggested,  I should take the sup norm and then try to show equicontinuity and boundedness? So what happens with other norms/metric, say a general norm/metric function, can I arrive at condition under which the set will be bounded or equicontinuous? This is just my curiosity (Do we need functional analysis?) Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Equicontinuity holds for any norm with the property $\|f\|_\infty \leq C\|f\|$ for some constant $C$.